# Find the constant term of a generating function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a generating function for $S_1$: $g_1(z)=\frac{1}{4}(z+z^{-1}+2)$, and I want to know the distribution of $S_n=\sum_nS_1$. According to the convolution stuff, $g_n(z)=\frac{1}{4^n}(z+z^{-1}+2)^n$, but how can I get its constant term? Is there a method without really expanding the polynomial term? Because the comment says that this problem can be solved without using generating function if I went through the expanding process, I guess the implication is that it won't be necessary with generating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $g_n(\mathrm e^{\mathrm it})=2^{-n}(1+\cos t)^n=\cos^{2n}(t/2)$ hence the general formula
$$
P[S_n=0]=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g_n(\mathrm e^{\mathrm it})\mathrm dt
$$
reads in this case as
$$
P[S_n=0]=\frac2\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}(\cos t)^{2n}\mathrm dt
$$
Does this ring [a bell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)?

Comment: thanks! Though the textbook stated explicitly that z is complex, I didn't look at it that way before